# How to match value from an array in cyphery?

Tags: neo4j

```
MATCH (s:Product {id:'4538875'})-[r]-> (o:Attributes) 
WHERE any(key in keys(o) WHERE o[key] contains 'type-c') 
return o
```

In this query, the value of 'o[key]' could be an array or a String. When it is an array, the "contains" keyword won't work. So how to modify this query to be able to match against each value of an array?

Comment: How how to convert it (when it's an array) to a string? The 'toString()' method won't work for array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert an array to a string, then the [`REDUCE`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce) function will help you (just need a value that is not an array to convert to an array):

```
WITH [1,2,3,'abc'] as array, 
     'abc' as string
RETURN REDUCE(res='', e in [] + array | res + e) as arrayToString,
       REDUCE(res='', e in [] + string | res + e) as testStringToString
```

Or you can use [the `toString` function from the APOC library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_conversion_functions):

```
RETURN apoc.convert.toString([1,2,3,'abc'])
```

**Update**

Without conversion to a string, you can simply walk through the array. For example:

```
MERGE (T1:Test {id: 1}) SET T1.value1 = 'abc'
MERGE (T2:Test {id: 2}) SET T2.value2 = ['def', 'xyzab']
WITH true AS tmp

MATCH (T:Test) 
WHERE ANY(k IN KEYS(T) 
  WHERE ANY(v IN [] + T[k] 
    WHERE toString(v) CONTAINS 'ab'
  )
) 
RETURN T
```

Comment: The 'apoc' is more concise, but a little slower, with 'total 620 db hits', while the loop version costs 'total 520 db hits'.